# Is not possible change MySQL's port at Fedora Server 36

Tags: fedora, configuration, mysql, port

For Fedora **Server** 36 was installed `MySQL` 8 Community through the `.rpm` from [MySQL Community Downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/). Now according with the [Editing Conf. Files](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/installing-mysql-mariadb/#_editing_conf_files) section is indicated to use the `/etc/my.cnf.d/community-mysql-server.cnf` file, but it does not exist, it because the `/etc/my.cnf.d/` directory is empty, the truly valid file is `/etc/my.cnf/` where it currently contains:

```
[mysql]
#
# many comments
#
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Well if is added `port=3307` as

```
[mysql]
#
# many comments
#
port=3007
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

saved the file and executed the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop mysqld
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

for the second command fails with the following message:

```
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysqld.service" for details
```

For the `systemctl status mysqld.service` command shows

[image]

With the `journalctl -xeu mysqld.service` command shows

From above something *Error 13: (Permission denied)*

[image]

With the `sudo cat /var/log/mysqld.log` command shows

[image]

From above:

```
Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Permission denied
Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3307?
```

With the `sudo lsof -i -P` command shows

[image]

What is missing or what should be done?

**Note**: I have this situation even with port `3308`. Of course if is declared `3306` explicitly all work fine.

Comment: Maybe this is a SELinux issue (or firewall perhaps), check [this](http://www.pervasivecode.com/blog/2008/03/29/making-selinux-allow-a-nonstandard-mysql-port-number-on-centos-51/). Maybe something like this works: ` sudo /usr/sbin/semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 3307`

Comment: Yep, it's a SeLinux issue. By default it allows MySQL only to listen on port 3306.

Comment: Do NOT post images where plain text will do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it seems it is the correct path - and of course it is based on your experience - because I am not an expert in Linux - why the error message was not more clearer? Indicating something like _" ... port blocked by SELinux ..."_? - apart, due there is a lot of information is more readable the Figures than plain text

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I confirmed your command works, pls put your comment as an answer to mark it as valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to SELinux [(Troubleshooting problems related to SELinux)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/troubleshooting-problems-related-to-selinux_using-selinux) because as
@Artem S. Tashkinov said, this allows mysql only to listen on port 3306. So if you want to be able to use another port you (e.g. 3307) you will need to run this command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 3307
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe port should be specified in `[mysqld]` section - for server settings?
Section `[mysql]` is for client program.